# Different color contrast between same image

Tags: html, css, image

This is how to original image look like:
[image: how to show the original image]

And here is how to show it on website:
[image: how to show it on Website]

My question is why to change the black colour between the original image and the image which showed on website, and what can I do to avoid it?

Here is how to call the image on HTML:

```
<img id="logo" src="Photo/my-logo.png" alt=""/>
```

Here's how to call the image on CSS:

```
#logo {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2%;
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    left: 0%;
    color:  #101010;
}
```

The original image has **805px x 204px**, therefore when write `width: 100%;` it to come many place from Monitor... .
I to try with **Gimp** the image to scaling, what the image to come is similar as the second image...
With **Gimp** scaling the image to **265px x 67px**, how to show it...

[how to show the image later the scaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTqc6.png)

When give **width: 100%;** come same problemm..

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: Thanks!, i remove it , `<img id="logo" src="Photo/my-logo2.png" alt="">`, what nothing to change...

Comment: Might be because you are resizing it, try setting it at 100% `width` and see if the color is the same as the original

Comment: Very Thanks for your answer!, Thanks to your answer I think now I know what I should do ..because of the image too big it is, with **100%**, I'll with **Gimp** escalate it...

Comment: How I to show there are People that found my question stupidly, when from them so easy it is, can please give me the solution....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!, ..the verity, was on other Forum that people to say to me...

**1.** In **Gimp** do **Filters > Generic > Erode** , this will thicken up the black ,

[how to show later this step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmTwq.png)

**2.** scale with **Gimp** the image  to **265px  67px**.

**3.** how it to show the logo on the Website..

[how to show on the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbC7N.png)